# Dynamically create objects in JS and append them to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building an HTML table where one of the columns has dynamically created divs with background color and text content. I've been able to create the divs and add styling...but I cannot get the text content to show up inside the div. Here's what I'm trying to achieve (see image below):

[image]

...and here's where I am at so far:
[image]

I'm thinking of the div with background color as the "parent div" and the div with text content as "child div".  I tried appending the text div to the parent div, setting the z-index of the text higher, but that did not work.  I also tried just setting the `innerText` content of the parent div itself, which also did not work.Can anyone help me understand how I can get the text to show up inside the div, per the example screenshot?

Thanks in advance. Here's some working code to demonstrate the problem:

```js
const populateProjectsTable = (data) => {
  // Store table id in variable
  let tableRef = document.getElementById("recent-projects-table-body");
  // Clear out table data before loading new results
  $(tableRef).empty();
  $(tableRef).show();

  sampleData.forEach((item) => {
    // Insert a row at the end of the table
    let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);


    // Name Cell
    let nameCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    nameCell.className = "left-align";
    // Name text and container
    let nameText = document.createTextNode("name");
    nameCell.appendChild(nameText);

    // Assessments Cell
    let assessmentsCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
    let assessmentsText = document.createTextNode("assessment count");
    assessmentsCell.className = "right-align";
    assessmentsCell.appendChild(assessmentsText);

    // Count Cell
    let countCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
    countCell.className = "center-align"
    // Div to hold circles
    let countsDiv = document.createElement('div');
    // Create individual circles
    // green
    let greenCount = document.createElement("div");
    greenCount.className = "circle green"
    let greenText = utils.createElements("div", "circle-text");
    $(greenText).text("1")
    greenCount.append(greenText);

    // yellow
    let yellowCount = document.createElement('div');
    yellowCount.className = "circle yellow";
    let yellowText = utils.createElements("div", "circle-text");
    $(yellowText).text("1")
    yellowCount.append(yellowText);

    // red
    let redCount = document.createElement("div");
    redCount.className = "circle red";
    let redText = utils.createElements("div", "circle-text");
    $(redText).text("1")
    redCount.append(redText);

    // Append to div
    countsDiv.append(greenCount, yellowCount, redCount);

    // Append div to cell
    countCell.appendChild(countsDiv);
  });
};
```

```css
/* ==================================================
Table styling
================================================== */

.table {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  overflow: clip;
}

th {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: -1px;
}

.table-th,
.table td {
  padding: 8px;
  height: 40px;
}

.table>thead>tr {
  background-color: orange;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fce8c3;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.table__small {
  width: fit-content;
}

.table__wide {
  width: 100%;
}

.right-align {
  text-align: right;
}

.center-align {
  text-align: center;
}

.left-align {
  text-align: left;
}


/* ==================================================
Circle styling
================================================== */

.circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  line-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4px;
}

.circle-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 100;
}

.counts-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="recent-projects-table" class="table" style="display: table;">
  <thead class="sticky">
    <tr id="projects-config-tr">
      <!-- Project Name -->
      <th class="sticky left-align table-th table-column__name">
        Recent Projects
      </th>
      <!-- Assessments -->
      <th class="sticky right-align table-th">Assessments</th>
      <!-- Counts -->
      <th class="sticky center-align table-th">Counts</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="recent-projects-table-body">
    <tr>
      <td class="left-align">Buddy Games</td>
      <td class="right-align">3</td>
      <td>
        <div class="counts-div">
          <div class="circle green" style="
    z-index: 2;
">
            <div class="circle-text" style="
    position: absolute;
">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle yellow">1</div>
          <div class="circle red">1</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-align">Richie Rich, The Poor House</td>
      <td class="right-align">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="counts-div">
          <div class="circle green">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle yellow">1</div>
          <div class="circle red">1</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-align">NewProject1</td>
      <td class="right-align">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="counts-div">
          <div class="circle green">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle yellow">1</div>
          <div class="circle red">1</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-align">TestProject</td>
      <td class="right-align">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="counts-div">
          <div class="circle green">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle yellow">1</div>
          <div class="circle red">1</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you do the `z-index` with `stacking-context` in mind? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the dynamically added elements, but with CSS applied to `.circle` class. Because it has a `line-height: 500px` the font will try to create lines of `500px` high with the actual text somewhere in the middle.

Remove that line and your text will show.

```css
/* ==================================================
Table styling
================================================== */

.table {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  overflow: clip;
}

th {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: -1px;
}

.table-th,
.table td {
  padding: 8px;
  height: 40px;
}

.table>thead>tr {
  background-color: orange;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fce8c3;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.table__small {
  width: fit-content;
}

.table__wide {
  width: 100%;
}

.right-align {
  text-align: right;
}

.center-align {
  text-align: center;
}

.left-align {
  text-align: left;
}


/* ==================================================
Circle styling
================================================== */

.circle {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4px;
}

.circle-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 100;
}

.counts-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="recent-projects-table" class="table" style="display: table;">
  <thead class="sticky">
    <tr id="projects-config-tr">
      <!-- Project Name -->
      <th class="sticky left-align table-th table-column__name">
        Recent Projects
      </th>
      <!-- Assessments -->
      <th class="sticky right-align table-th">Assessments</th>
      <!-- Counts -->
      <th class="sticky center-align table-th">Counts</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="recent-projects-table-body">
    <tr>
      <td class="left-align">Buddy Games</td>
      <td class="right-align">3</td>
      <td>
        <div class="counts-div">
          <div class="circle green">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle yellow">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle red">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-align">Richie Rich, The Poor House</td>
      <td class="right-align">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="counts-div">
          <div class="circle green">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle yellow">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle red">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-align">NewProject1</td>
      <td class="right-align">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="counts-div">
          <div class="circle green">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle yellow">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle red">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-align">TestProject</td>
      <td class="right-align">0</td>
      <td>
        <div class="counts-div">
          <div class="circle green">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle yellow">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle red">
            <div class="circle-text">1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Typo in description: `.circle` instead of `.circle-text`?

Comment: OMG - you're right - how in the world did I miss that. Thank you!!